# xml fo DITA add extra font

Tags: xml, fonts

I try to formulate my question as well as possible. We want to add the Font Titillium-regular.otf and Titillium -bold.otf font for a DITA OT publication process.

The font is added in the Fonts folder and I Styled all the relevant content into this font. After a publishing process, the wrong font is used. Who can help me.

Please step by step instructions.

Thank you for now

Comment: What FO formatter? Typically you need to add to the formatter configuration

Comment: Hi Kevin. 
I work with Antenna House. This is the first time i must add a font.
I found some info on several website, one said 

QUOTE
" If you are using Antenna House's XSL Formatter on Windows, then you can automatically use all the fonts that are registered in the Windows Fonts utility. If you are on another platform, then you add fonts to the Font Configuration file as described in the Antenna House documentation."

Im working on a Windows, so do i have to register the wanted fonts then?

Comment: A pitty nobody has an anwser for me

Comment: I do not use AH so I do not know